# Get-Childitem trying to get the registry entry from current working directory

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get registry key values but i am facing issues.

Following is the command i tried to execute.

```
Get-ChildItem "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mycompany\MyProj\Model" | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath}
```

But in registry key path appended with current working directory and produce unexpected issue like below.

```
PS C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyDoc\Core\NodeRenameMaster> Get-ChildItem "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\S
FTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mycompany\MyProj\Model" | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.pspath}
Get-ChildItem : Cannot find path 'C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\MyDoc\Core\NodeRenameMaster\HKEY_
LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mycompany\MyProj\Model' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:14
+ Get-ChildItem <<<<  "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Mycompany\MyProj\Model" | ForEach-Object {Get-Item
Property $_.pspath}
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Users\Admini...\Model:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFound
   Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Why it occurs  ? How to solve this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The path is invalid, replace 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE' with 'HKLM:\' and 'SFTWARE' with 'SOFTWARE'

Comment: You might also want to check out help about_path_syntax for more information about paths.

Comment: Another trick (I know you know Shay) is to use the fully qualified path e.g. <PS Provider>::Path. In the case of the registry it would be `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software`. This is useful say if you need to process registry paths that are in the non-powershell format. All you have to do is prefix `Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\Registry::` and you will be good to go.